# Circuit builder for beginner showing the light of LEDs and electical flow

Tags: simulation, circuit-design

I'm looking for a virtual circuit designer application (for Windows). I assume the application has a design mode and "debug" mode to see electrical flow and lights of the LEDs (for example, if an LED turns on and off every second the application shows that action). I would want to know your suggestions of which application can do this better.

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at Multisim of National Instruments. It's a simulator for electronic circuit design and you are also able to licht LEDs. There also a library with common used components.
http://www.ni.com/multisim/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general term is *circuit simulator*. This one is most likely what you are looking for:

http://www.falstad.com/circuit/

Though there's no differentiation between *design mode* and *debug mode*, it still is quite powerful, since it simulates on-the-fly as you draw.

---

As you progress, this will become insufficient and you will have to convert to something like [LTSpice.](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/#LTspice)

Comment: This is also a good site for beginners because it provides a lot of neat sample circuits to learn from